# Modulus of singular inner function $\phi(z)=\exp\left(\frac{z+1}{z-1}\right)$

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis

I'm trying to show the following the function $\phi(z)=\exp\left(\frac{z+1}{z-1}\right)$

$$|\phi(z)|=\left|\exp\left(\frac{z+1}{z-1}\right)\right|=\exp\left(-\frac{1-|z|^{2}}{|1-z|^{2}}\right)$$

Inner function is a bounded analytic function $\phi$ in the unit disk $\mathbb{D}$ such that $|\phi(z)|=1$ almost everywhere on the unit circle (boundary of $\mathbb{D}$) and but I don't really see how the above can be explicitly shown.

Comment: What inequality?

Comment: @RobertIsrael It was a typo. Thank you for catching that. I have edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$|\exp(w)| = \exp(\text{Re}(w))$, so the claim is that
$$\text{Re}\left( \frac{z+1}{z-1}\right) = - \frac{1 - |z|^2}{|1-z|^2}$$
Now
$$ \eqalign{\text{Re}\left(\frac{z+1}{z-1}\right)  &= \frac{z+1}{2(z-1)} + \frac{\overline{z}+1}{2(\overline{z}-1)}\cr &= \frac{z \overline{z}-1}{(z-1)(\overline{z}-1)}\cr
&= - \frac{1 - |z|^2}{|1-z|^2}}$$